# Code produces an extra line and doesn't read the first character array when using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf

I've got this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void countCharacter(char str[], char *p, int Count)
{
    p=str;
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        Count++;
        p++;
    }

    printf("The string, %s, has %d characters", str, Count-1);
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    char *p;
    int Count = 0;

    printf("Enter any string:  \n");
    scanf("%c", str);
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    
    countCharacter(str, p, Count);
    return 0;
}
```

*For this particular exercise I was not allowed to use the `sizeof` operator or `strlen()` function *

The code is supposed to count the number of characters in an array and give that as the output. For example, if I were to input `test` I should get the following output:

```
Enter any string:  
test
The string, test, has 4 characters.
```

However, I end up with this instead:

```
Enter any string:  
 test
The string test
 has 4 characters
```

Any help on why this is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm gussing the string you are imputting (and you could verify this with a debugger) includes a newline. E.g., when you type in `test<enter>`, C stores it as `test\n`. Later, when you print it, the newline also gets printed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: Yeah it did! Thank you for the input it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

From C11 standard regarding `fgets`:

> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a **new-line character (which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

Based on this, the fgets includes the new-line character `\n`.  You could correct the code by removing the line feed character.  For example: `str[strlen(str) - 1] = ‘\0’;`.

Another thing worth noting is that line `scanf("%c", str);` writes the first character entered to the array, which is immediately discarded by `fgets`.  So for the test case discussed in the question, I get the result:

```
Enter any string:
test
The string, est
, has 3 characters
```

Also, variable `p` in `main()` is never initialized in the program and is immediately discarded inside of `countCharacter()`.  I'm not sure of the intent, but it seems that it would make sense to move the variable definition `char *p;` from inside of `main()` to inside of `countCharacter()` and get rid of parameter `p` of `countCharacter()`.